# Vuetify full-screen carousel

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

For the home page of my site I am planning to have a fullscreen carousel with some text on top of this. I could make the carousel, but not have it fullscreen (I want it so that you never have to scroll, no matter the device size. I have tried several things, but none work.

I have a toolbar at the top of the page which seems to interfere and cause these to not work.

I have tried:

```
<v-carousel style="height: 100%" hide-controls>

<v-carousel fullscreen hide-controls>

<v-carousel fill-height hide-controls>
```

But all of them either make the whole thing disappear or make the carousel stick with what seems to be the default maximum height.

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EwqWqP

How could I get a fullscreen carousel?

Comment: Share more code.

Comment: @pirs I have updated the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`height: 100%` does not work, because your parent element for example `<body>` or `<some-other-div>` needs some height too.

What you can do is setting your parent container `height:100vh` and your carousel to `height:100%`, like:

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-toolbar></v-toolbar>
    <v-carousel style="height:100%">
      <v-carousel-item v-for="(item,i) in items" v-bind:src="item.src" :key="i"></v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#inspire {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

This seems to work for me → [Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVWWwp)

Comment: This didn’t work as vh seems to ignore the toolbar. I updated the question appropriately.

Comment: I did not know you could set style properties on vuetify components like they are normal html tags. Thanks for this answer

Answer (score 3):

With Vuetify 2.5.8 you can set height="100vh" in your v-carousel tag.

```
 <v-carousel height="100vh">
```

Comment: Man I was struggling for a while this really helped me thanks !

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I wanted, thank you.